# Prevent non-ASCII strings being written to Column

Tags: postgresql, unicode, sqlalchemy

I want to prevent that non-ASCII string are written into a specific column in my postgres db table. I thought about using `constrains`, but I get an error message when trying to use any of the encoding convert functions. Using other string functions like `lower` or `btrim` worked w/o problem.

```
metadata = MetaData()
constrains = [CheckConstraint('lower(name) = name', name='enforce_lower'),
            CheckConstraint('utf8_to_ascii(name) = name', name='prevent_non_ascii')]
concepts_table = Table('test20', metadata,
                       Column('name', Text, *constrains))
metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=False)
```

The error message is:

`(ProgrammingError) function utf8_to_ascii(text) does not exist`

This is my postgresql version:

```
SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `utf8_to_ascii(text)` function in postgresql (as error message states ;) ). Instead there is defined conversion (more on conversions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createconversion.html) of this name: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#CONVERSION-NAMES

To utilize existing conversion use `convert(string bytea, src_encoding name, dest_encoding name)`

Try using following constraint definition:

```
CheckConstraint("encode(convert(name::bytea, 'UTF8'::name, 'SQL_ASCII'::name), 'escape') = name", name='prevent_non_ascii')
```

Comment: Thanks! But this results in following error: `(ProgrammingError) function convert(text, unknown, unknown) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Now it says `(ProgrammingError) function convert(text, name, name) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` Also I found utf6_to_ascii on this website: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Updated once more ;), Mhmmm... I can't see `utf6_to_ascii` there.